# Cocos2d update:(ccTime)dt giving screwed up values

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Inside of a class that subclasses `CCNode`, I have scheduled an `-update:(ccTime)dt` method. I also have a bunch of behavior objects that don't subclass `CCNode`, but also have an  `-update:(ccTime)dt` method. Here's the inside of my `CCNode`'s `update` method:

```
-(void)update:(ccTime)dt{
    for(Behavior *currentBehavior in behaviors){
        [currentBehavior update:dt];
    }
}
```

When I `NSLog` the `dt` value passed into my `CCNode`'s `update`, it prints out normal values (0.116699, 0.162726). However, when I `NSLog` the `dt` value from inside the behaviors' `update` methods, the printed numbers are all of a sudden really screwed up (0.000, 36893488147419103232, -2.000). It's the strangest thing. When I debug it, I'll see  that the first `dt` value is normal, and then I'll step inside the behavior's `update`, and the value will suddenly change to something crazy. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't have `-update:(ccTime)dt` in my behavior class's .m file, and my theory is that it took the complier extra time to look for the method selector, which therefore screwed up the ccTime.

Comment: This makes no sense at all.